# Windows Desktop application wrote with Flutter, compiled to machine code or bytecode?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I want to build an application using flutter.

According to [Flutter website](https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/desktop):

> Get native-compiled performance without large browser engine dependencies.

Are flutter app's compiled to machine code or byte code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to run Dart programs. Please refer to the [dart compile](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile) documentation.

Quoting from referenced page, a few of the compilation options include:

- **exe**: A standalone, architecture-specific executable file containing the source code compiled to machine code and a small Dart runtime.
- **aot-snapshot**: An architecture-specific file containing the source code compiled to machine code, but no Dart runtime.
- **jit-snapshot**: An architecture-specific file with an intermediate representation of all source code, plus an optimized representation of the source code that executed during a training run of the program. JIT-compiled code can have faster peak performance than AOT code if the training data is good.

> Note: You don’t need to compile Dart programs before running them. Instead, you can use the `dart run` command, which uses the Dart VM’s JIT (just-in-time) compiler--a feature that’s especially useful during development.

Answer (score 1):

A Windows desktop application written with Flutter would be compiled to machine code. Flutter is a mobile app development framework that uses the Dart programming language. It can be used to develop apps for both Android and iOS, as well as for desktop platforms such as Windows and MacOS, using the same codebase. When you build a Flutter app, it is compiled to machine code, which is then executed by the target device's processor.